# Python ctypes OSError: [WinError 998] Invalid access to memory location

Tags: python, nasm, ctypes

I am using ctypes to load a 64-bit DLL written in NASM.  The command is:

```
ThisDLL = ctypes.WinDLL(r"C:/Temp2/Test_Project_2/Std_Math_Formulas.dll")
```

The error message is:

```
OSError: [WinError 998] Invalid access to memory location

In order to reduce the possibilities, I changed the code to an extremely simple, barebones DLL:

; Header Section

[BITS 64]

export SimpleTest

section .data

var1: dq 24

var2: dq 254

answer: dq 0

section .text

SimpleTest:

mov rax,[var1]

mov rbx,[var2]

add rax,rbx

mov [answer],rax

ret

* * * * *
```

Yet I still get "Invalid access to memory location."

I have researched this for hours, and this message comes up in many different situations, but I haven't found any satisfactory answers.

Any ideas would be most appreciated.

Comment: _RBX_ is a non-volatile register. If you change it you have to restore it in your function. What happens if you do `mov rax,[var1]`  `add rax,[var2]` `mov [answer],rax` ?

Comment: Michael, thanks very, very much.  Your solution fixed the problem.  Yes, NASM and GoLink.